# WebSQL Databases between two different pages?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, html

Is there any particular way in which we can access the Web SQL Database of one page, by other page. To make it more clear, suppose a.com creates the database DB and store some info. Now b.com comes and want to access the same database DB. Is there a way? Or are there any alternatives to do this? I tried to implement in HTML5 and Javascript but the databases as well as the localStorages are confining only to particular pages, I want this to be cross the pages.

Comment: When you say different pages, you mean different domains?

Comment: If they could, this would be a security problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a script on http://one-domain.com/ to be able to read from the database of http://another-domain.org then no -- the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is applied to localStorage and Web SQL databases, which means that only scripts running on the same domain as the script that created the database are allowed to have access to the database.

Your best bet in that case would be to send the data from `one-domain` back to the server and have the server of `one-domain` push the data over to `another-domain` (or else, if they are on the same network, provide a shared resource they can communicate over.)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by including a utility iFrame with a database access script from b.com in your a.com pages and vice versa. You can then use cross document messaging to transfer information. Note that postMessage only transmits a simple string and if you're trying to pass structured information then a.com and b.com will have to agree on a serialization. So...it's a hack.

Comment: Is this really effective? Sounds like an avenue for a security vulnerability, or do I understand differently?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jedp/3005816